# Parsing Array for a Stacked Area Chart in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to modfiy the example stacked area chart [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211#)

currently it gives me an error as such:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,22770LNaN,21…".
```

at this line: `.attr('d', area);`

This is my code so far:

```
let margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    let parseDate = d3.timeParse('%m/%d/%Y');

    let x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(['Detractors', 'Passives' , 'Promoters'])
        .range(['#e81123', '#a0a1a2', '#7fba00']);

    let stack = d3.stack();

    let area = d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
        .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

    let g = this._svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    let data = [
                { 'date': '04/23/12' , 'Detractors': 20 , 'Passives': 30 , 'Promoters': 50 },
                { 'date': '04/24/12' , 'Detractors': 32 , 'Passives': 19 , 'Promoters': 42 },
                { 'date': '04/25/12' , 'Detractors': 45 , 'Passives': 11 , 'Promoters': 44 },
                { 'date': '04/26/12' , 'Detractors': 20 , 'Passives': 13 , 'Promoters': 64 }];

    // console.log(myData.map(function (d) { return d.key; }));

    // console.log('KEYS: '+ keys);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        console.log(parseDate(d.date));
        return parseDate(d.date); }));
    // let keys = (d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== 'date'; }));
    z.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== 'date'; }));
    // z.domain(keys);
    stack.keys(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== 'date'; }));

    let layer = g.selectAll('.layer')
        .data(stack(data))
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'layer');

    layer.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'area')
        .style('fill', function(d) {
            // console.log('d.key: ' + d.key);
            console.log('d.key: ' + d.key +  ' color: ' + z(d.key));
            return z(d.key); })
        .attr('d', area);

    layer.filter(function(d) { return d[d.length - 1][1] - d[d.length - 1][0] > 0.01; })
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', width - 6)
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y((d[d.length - 1][0] + d[d.length - 1][1]) / 2); })
        .attr('dy', '.35em')
        .style('font', '10px sans-serif')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text(function(d) {
            // console.log('key label: ' + d.key);
            return d.key; });


    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // console.log(height);
    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5, '%'));

    }
```

I am just trying to parse the array so I can have the date, keys and value parsing properly. I just can't seem to get it right.

Much help is appreciated!!

Comment: The fix was my data should've been this:

`let data = [
                    { 'date': '04/23/12' , 'Detractors': 0.20 , 'Passives': 0.30 , 'Promoters': 0.50 },
                    { 'date': '04/24/12' , 'Detractors': 0.32 , 'Passives': 0.19 , 'Promoters': 0.42 },
                    { 'date': '04/25/12' , 'Detractors': 0.45 , 'Passives': 0.11 , 'Promoters': 0.44 },
                    { 'date': '04/26/12' , 'Detractors': 0.20 , 'Passives': 0.13 , 'Promoters': 0.64 }];`

Answer (score 0):

The specific error that you are getting is due to the format of the date in your data.  You have a line commented out in your code: `let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");`  You do want to use the d3.timeParse function to transform your data to date format:

```
let tp = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y")
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
  data[i].date = tp(data[i].date) 
}
```

Comment: I have updated the line to be
 `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
            console.log(parseDate(d.date));
            return parseDate(d.date); }));`

I've even tried it your way with the for loop and this is still giving me the error at the same line with the area function

Comment: Here's the fiddle I created to test it.  Seemed like I did a lot of cleanup on the formatting, but I don't think I changed other parts of your code - maybe adding a missing paren or something.  If you comment out my for loop - you get an error...with the loop, no error (but the chart doesn't render completely)
https://jsfiddle.net/genestd/p7yabxup/

Comment: I've placed the for loop where you've placed it and it just shows the entire chart in red. Like you were saying the rest of the graph is not rendering or the rest of the data isn't I'm not quite sure the parenthesis I have all match I believe.